# Failed to instantiate java.util.List using constructor NO_CONSTRUCTOR with arguments ]

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

i am getting

```
Failed to instantiate java.util.List using constructor NO_CONSTRUCTOR with arguments ] with root cause
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [java.util.List]: Specified class is an interface
```

this exception while updating the mongodb nested document.

the problem is the same as it is dicscuseed it this link

http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/nosql/724397-mapping-exception-with-mongodb-aggregation-framework

but still no clue how to solve it. anyone gone thorugh this??

Comment: I've got no experience with mongodb but the mapper tried to instanciate a `List` which won't work because it is an interface. A workaround would be to convince your mapper to instead instantiate an `ArrayList` when `List` is needed.

Comment: Edit : actually, the issue in the thread you showed was that the query returned an Object instead of a single-element List, thus making the mapper fail to recognize an array. Is your issue the same ?

Comment: @JeremyGrand can you help me out to how to do it?

Comment: @JeremyGrand exaclty my issue

Comment: Its little vague without the code. Consider adding complete code including sample documents which when run will throw the exception

Comment: code is exactly like in the given link, please open to view it @veeram

Comment: so you are also unwinding the array in the aggregation ? If yes try to group at the end of pipeline to change it back to array so spring can map it correctly and see if that fixes error. I can only suggest things and cant answer for your case without the example.

Comment: Yesterday, I got the same issue in my project and figured out it seems to be a Java bean mapping issue. I mean you stored the wrong/incompatible data structure in DB which is not equivalent to mapped Java bean.

Answer (score 8):

I just had the same problem and solved it thanks to:
[Mongo db java unwind operation in aggregate query throwing exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38539346/mongo-db-java-unwind-operation-in-aggregate-query-throwing-exception)

When in the aggregation the unwind happened, the results are flattened so in my case I had a class like:

```
MyClass {
   String _id;
   List<SomeObject> objectList;
}
```

The exception occurs because of the flattening, the results on my list object instead of coming up in an array, now are just a single object because of the $unwind.

What I did to fix this was to create the same class without the list:

```
MyClassAggregationResult {
  String _id;
  SomeObject objectList;
}
```

This way the results are mapped correctly.

Hope this works for you as well.

Answer (score 1):

change to as below it should work

String _id;

SomeObject objectList;

Comment: How can this work? we need a list of SomeObject, right? Aren't you changing the definition?